# Child process return wrong value

Tags: process, fork

I want see what will `getppid()` is returned function when child process will execute. I entered `sleep(10)` to complete parent process. Actually I should obtain "**CHILD: My parent PID -- 1**\n", because this child process should have init process as parent if parent does not call `wait()`.
But I am obtaining **PPID=959**. This is not init-process. This PPID corresponds to some `/sbin/upstart --user` command.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
 int status;
 pid_t pid, ch_pid;

 switch(pid=fork()) {
 case -1:
    perror("Fork failed");
    exit(1);
  case  0:
    sleep(10);
    printf("\nCHILD: This is child process!\n");
    printf("CHILD: My PID is-- %d\n", getpid());
    printf("CHILD: My parent PID -- %d\n", getppid());
    //sleep(5);
    exit(0);
  default:
    //sleep(60); 
    /*Prohibit PP to execute*/
    printf("PARENT: This is parent process!\n");
    printf("PARENT: My PID -- %d\n", getpid());
    printf("PARENT: My child PID %d\n",pid);
    printf("PARENT: My parent PID %d\n",getppid());
    exit(0);
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Don't pay attention on comments.

Comment: I am getting the correct results when running this code on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I don't know what you are seeing. Could I get the exact output from your run?

Comment: http://imagehost.cc/image/aUWdc. I entered ps 914 command standalone